# How to filter out points with negative depth in cv.projectPoints

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

When using [cv.projectPoints](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1019495a2c8d1743ed5cc23fa0daff8c), it just returns corresponding 2D imagePoints with the same Size of 3D objectPoints. However, it is usually necessary to filter out invalid points with negative depth (**Constraint 1**) or out of the image bounds (**Constraint 2**). An example function to implement these contraints is shown below.

```py
import numpy as np

def nptran(pcd:np.ndarray, rigdtran:np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    pcd_ = pcd.copy().T  # (N, 3) -> (3, N)
    pcd_ = rigdtran[:3, :3] @ pcd_ + rigdtran[:3, [3]]
    return pcd_.T

def npproj(pcd:np.ndarray, extran:np.ndarray, intran:np.ndarray, img_shape:tuple) -> np.ndarray:
    H, W = img_shape
    pcd_ = nptran(pcd, extran)  # (N, 3)
    pcd_ = intran @ pcd_.T  # (3, N)
    u, v, w = pcd_[0], pcd_[1], pcd_[2]
    raw_index = np.arange(u.size)
    rev = w > 0  # filter out points with negative depth
    raw_index = raw_index[rev]
    u = u[rev]/w[rev]
    v = v[rev]/w[rev]
    rev2 = (0<=u) * (u<W) * (0<=v) * (v<H)  # filter out points out of image bounds
    return np.stack((u[rev2],v[rev2]),axis=1), raw_index[rev2]  # return imagepoints and inlier indices
```

However, I don't know how to implement **Constraint 1** using `cv.projectPoints`. Is there any possible ways to write an auxiliary function to help `cv.projectPoints` return such inlier indices ?

Any help will be truely appreciated.

**PS:**
It is feasible to pre-project these points onto the image using a customed function and filter the input ObjectPoints of `cv.projectPoints` with pre-computed inlier indices, but this leads to repeated computation.

```py
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

def toMat(rvec:np.ndarray, tvec:np.ndarray):
    """rvec and tvec to SE3 Matrix

    Args:
        rvec (`np.ndarray`): 1x3 rotation vector\n
        tvec (`np.ndarray`): 1x3 translation vector
        
    Returns:
        SE3: 4x4 `np.ndarray`
    """
    R = Rotation.from_rotvec(rvec)
    mat = np.eye(4)
    mat[:3,:3] = R.as_matrix()
    mat[:3,3] = tvec
    return mat

def npproj_jac(pcd:np.ndarray, rvec:np.ndarray, tvec:np.ndarray, intran:np.ndarray, img_shape:tuple):
    distCoeffs = np.zeros(4)
    extran = toMat(rvec, tvec)
    _, rev_idx = npproj(pcd, extran, intran, img_shape)
    img_pts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(pcd[rev_idx], rvec, tvec, intran, distCoeffs)
    jac:np.ndarray = jac.reshape(-1,2,jac.shape[-1])  # N, 2, 10+numDistCoeffs
    return img_pts, jac[...,:6], rev_idx
```

It is valuable to realize this function for `cv.projectPoints` because it also returns Jacobian Matrix of each points.